# kendo ui js grid date format does not work

Tags: javascript, datetime, kendo-ui

this is how i format the datetime in the grid:

```
{
     field: "StartDate",
     format: "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}",
     parseFormats: ["yyyy-MM-dd"],
     type: "date",
     width: "80px"
},
```

This datetime: `{2015-05-11 00:00:00}`
becomes this: `/Date(1431295200000)/`
in the grid. I fount a lot of examples like this one http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/Ahq6s/ but i just can't get it to work as i want

Comment: Here is that fiddle updated with your date format: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Ahq6s/396/ . Just make sure you set the schema on the datasource for that field to type: "date"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the kendo.toString method in a template to perform this :

```
{
     field: "StartDate",
     template: "#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(StartDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'MM/dd/yyyy') #",
     width: "80px"
},
```